# Excel, Target Column, Target Offset, possible to pull from another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have written the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
  If Target.Column = 6 Then
    Call Current30(Target.Offset(0, -4).Text, Target.Offset(0, 10).Text, Target.Offset(0, 11).Text)
  ElseIf Target.Column = 7 Then
    Call Current(Target.Offset(0, -4).Text, Target.Offset(0, 9).Text, Target.Offset(0, 10).Text)
  End If
End Sub
```

What it does if you don't understand, is takes the cell you click in, uses the row it is currently on and then selects 3 cells on the same row based on the offset of the selected cell. I have another part that spits this out so I can use it in something else.

I am planing on moving the information that's stored in those 3 cells it pulls to another sheet. However, I am not sure how I can accomplish the same task but pull from another sheet instead, can anyone help me out on this?

***EDIT***

To clarify this a little bit, the cell I would be selecting would be in one sheet and the information I need pulled from 3 cells on the same row would be in the second sheet.

Comment: I'm sure it's easy.. But I am also still a noob at VBA :)

Comment: Hi Jonathan, if you put four spaces at the front of each line of code it will format the whole thing as one code block for you, easier than messing with all those single quotes and it'll look neater too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working using the following VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column = 9 Then
        Call Email(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Target.Row).Text, _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & Target.Row).Text, _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & Target.Row).Text, _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & Target.Row).Text, _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F" & Target.Row).Text)
    End If
    Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub Email(ByVal VV As String, ByVal WW As String, ByVal XX As String, ByVal YY As String, ByVal ZZ As String)
    Dim dblShellRetn As Double
        dblShellRetn = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkeyU32.exe" & _
        Chr(32) & Chr(34) & "C:\Scripts\Script.ahk" & Chr(34) & _
        Chr(32) & Chr(34) & VV & Chr(34) & _
        Chr(32) & Chr(34) & WW & Chr(34) & _
        Chr(32) & Chr(34) & XX & Chr(34) & _
        Chr(32) & Chr(34) & YY & Chr(34) & _
        Chr(32) & Chr(34) & ZZ & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your existing code to the other worksheet module. So long as there's nothing in your `Current30()` or `Current()` routines that have hard references the current sheet (specifying it by name or number), you'll be golden.

If those *do* reference it explicitly, modify them to do all their work relative to the 3 cells you're passing in, or modify the subroutine call to pass in the current worksheet and use that.

**UPDATE** Based on the clarification in your OP:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim OtherSheet as worksheet

  Set OtherSheet = Workbooks("Sheet2") 'change the sheet name to suit
  If Target.Column = 6 Then
    Call Current30(OtherSheet.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Col-4).text, _
                   OtherSheet.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Col+10).text, _
                   OtherSheet.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Col+11).text)
  ElseIf Target.Column = 7 Then
    Call Current(OtherSheet.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Col-4).text, _
                 OtherSheet.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Col+9).text, _
                 OtherSheet.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Col+10).text)
  End If
End Sub
```

Should do it for you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you mean, I am still pretty new to VBA and mostly find my code from the internet and alter it to suit my needs lol.. Are you saying to move this portion, (Target.Offset(0, 0).Text, Target.Offset(0, -4).Text, Target.Offset(0, 10).Text, Target.Offset(0, 11).Text) or the whole Current() portion to the new sheet?

Comment: Move the entire `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)` to the other worksheet. You may need to also move `Current30()` and `Current()`, or qualify the references to them if you want/need to leave them where they are. For example: `Sheet1.Current30()`

Comment: Changing it to Sheet2, doesn't seem to work.. I would definitely need to leave the selection change event in Sheet1 but moving the Current() to Sheet2 wouldn't work either.. I could just be doing something wrong lol..

Comment: @Jonathan just saw your edit to the OP. Take a look at the code posted. That should do it, though you may have to tweak  the +/- bit, that's just off the top of my head. Make your first run in the debugger and make sure the math is working out correctly.

Comment: Sounds great thank you, I will give it a go in a few minutes and let you know how it goes. As for the +/- I keep moving things around so I am always having to change mine lol :)

Comment: Is this supposed to go in the first sheet or second sheet? I get a subscript out of range error..

Comment: `Target.Col` may need to be `Target.Column`. That code would go on the sheet where you expect the `_OnChange` event to fire. If you're getting `subscript out of range`, step through the code in the debugger and see what all the variables are (`Target.Row`, `Target.col`, etc) make sure they are all logical, then step into your `Current*` routines and see if they're getting what you're expecting.

Comment: It is saying that this portion "Set OtherSheet = Workbooks("Sheet2")" is out of range but I am not quite sure how to correct although I have been attempting to do so before posting again lol..